# Xamarin Forms Map Viewable Area event handler

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I have a Xamarin form map on my screen and I'm using PropertyChanged event to retrieve geolocation information from my server and display the proper pins on screen.

While coding the solution I noticed the PropertyChanged event is triggered multiple times (up to 10 times) with a single zoom or drag action on the map. This causes unnecessary calls to server which I want to avoid.

Ideally I want to make only one call to server when the final PropertyChanged event is called but I cant's find an easy solution to implement this.

At this point I've added a refresh button to my page that becomes enabled when a PropertyChanged event happens and I disable it after user uses the button.

Obviously this fixed the too many calls to server but made the solution manual.
I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to make the server call but do it automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to check for ```e.PropertyName```, maybe debug it and check what is actually being called and changed.
And then decide on which property change you want to make server call.

Comment: PropertyName always shows VisibleRegion so that won't work

Comment: And sender is also always the same?

Comment: Yes it is always the map object (the object I hooked the event handler to)

Comment: Posting some of your code would be helpful to find proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just test the `PropertyChanged` event on iOS side and it just triggered one time with a single zoom or drag action on the map.

While if it really triggered multiple times, you can use a timer to call the server when the final `PropertyChanged` event is called, for example:

```
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    Timer aTimer;
    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        customMap.PropertyChanged += CustomMap_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void CustomMap_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (aTimer != null)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Close();
        }

        aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;
        aTimer.Start();
    }

    private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();

        //do web request
        Console.WriteLine(sender);
        Console.WriteLine("CustomMap_PropertyChanged");
    }
}
```

In the above code, I set the Interval = 1 second, that means in 1 second, whatever how many times `PropertyChanged` triggered, only the last call will trigger the `ATimer_Elapsed` function.

The Interval can be set to any value depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing on Android and I see multiple calls, I'll implement your timer solution for now but I was hoping there is another way ...